# Can't assign value to column that was just created in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

For some reason when I run this, it says `Invalid column name 'col3'.`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE name = 'col3' AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id      
FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE name = 'table1')) BEGIN
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD col3 int
UPDATE table1 SET col3=col1+col2
END
```

But if I alter the table first and after the `END` of the `IF` I try to update the value of `col3` like this, it just works:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE name = 'col3' AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id      
FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE name = 'table1')) BEGIN
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD col3 int
END
UPDATE table1 SET col3=col1+col2
```

Why can't I update it when I create it?

Comment: My guess is the entire `BEGIN...END` block is being parsed before any of it is executed, and that's when it notices that the column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is a parse-time error - SQL Server is trying to validate the entire batch as a single, atomic operation. It doesn't see that you are *going* to add a column with that name, it just knows that there isn't a column with that name *now* - it evaluates this independently from all of the other statements in the batch. For the same reason you can't do this:

```
IF 1 = 1
  CREATE TABLE #t(i INT);
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #t(y INT);
```

Obviously you and I know that only one of those branches will ever execute, but the error message you get from SQL Server (there is already an object named #t) hints that it doesn't understand branching or sequencing.

Two ways to circumvent this:

1. Issue the two commands in separate batches. If you are using Management Studio, simply put a `GO` between the `ALTER` and the `UPDATE`. This will force Management Studio to evaluate the batches in dependency order. Or even more simply - highlight the `ALTER`, and run that, then highlight the `UPDATE`, and run that.
2. Execute the update using dynamic SQL.

   ```
   IF NOT EXISTS (blah blah)
   BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE dbo.table1 ADD col3 INT;
   END
   EXEC dbo.sp_executesql N'UPDATE dbo.table1 SET col3 = col1 + col2;';
   ```